# Equation system ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am to solve the following ODE:
$$
\begin{cases}
& x'=1 - \frac{1}{y} \\
& y'= \frac{1}{x-t}
\end{cases}
$$
and $x(0)=-1$, $y(0) = 1$

How can it be solved? My only idea was to obtain $y$ from the first equation
$$
y = \frac{1}{1-x'}
$$
and plug it into the first one:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1-x'}\right)'= \frac{1}{x-t}
$$
but that leads me nowhere. What is the trick?

Comment: Try using the sub $x-t = u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
& x'=1 - \frac{1}{y} \\
& y'= \frac{1}{x-t}
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
& (x-t)'= - \dfrac{1}{y} \\
& y'= \dfrac{1}{x-t}
\end{cases}$$
Rewrite it as:
$$\begin{cases}
& X'= - \dfrac{1}{y} \\
& y'= \dfrac{1}{X}
\end{cases}$$

$$X=\dfrac 1 {y'} \implies X'=-\dfrac {y''}{y'^2}$$
$$ \dfrac{1}{y}=\dfrac {y''}{y'^2}$$
$$ \dfrac{y'}{y}=\dfrac {y''}{y'}$$
$$(\ln y)'=(\ln y')'$$
Integrate.
$$\ln y=c_1+\ln y' \implies y=c_1y'$$
$$(\ln y)'=c \implies \ln y= ct+c_2$$
$$y(t)=c_2e^{c_1t}$$
$$y(0)=1 \implies c_2=1$$
$$y(t)=e^{c_1t}$$
You have from the first differential equation that:
$$x'=1-\dfrac 1y$$
$$x'=1-\dfrac 1{e^{c_1t}}$$
Integrate to get $x(t)$.
$$x(t)=t+c_3+\dfrac {e^{-c_1t}}{c_1}$$
$$x(0)=-1 \implies \dfrac 1{c_1}+c_3=-1$$
But you also have that:
$$y'(0)=1/(x(0)=-1$$
$$y'(t)=c_1e^{c_1t} \implies y'(0)=c_1=-1$$
$$\implies c_3=-1+1=0$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {\begin{cases}
& x(t)=t -e^{t} \\
& y(t)=e^{-t}
\end{cases}}$$

Comment: How is $(x-t)'$ the same as $x' - 1$? Isn't $(x-t)' = x't -x$?

Comment: Differentiate $(x-t)'=x'-1$ @НикитаВасильев  You differentiate with respect to $t$.

Comment: $x(t) = t + e^{-c_1t} \frac{1}{c_1c_2} + c_3$. That gives 3 different constants - is it possible to get non general solution? I know that $x(0) = -1$ and $y(0) = 1$.

Comment: You also have that $y'(0)=1/(x(0)=-1$ @НикитаВасильев

Comment: I got $c_1=-1,c_2=1,c_3=0$ @НикитаВасильев

Comment: I added some line I hope it's more clear @НикитаВасильев

Comment: Now it is perfectly clear. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome @НикитаВасильев